# NVIDIA displays UNCLAIMED on Ubuntu 18.04 (no secure boot)

Tags: 18.04, nvidia

I am trying to install CUDA on a desktop running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.  It was a WIN-10 machine that I dual booted with Ubuntu.  I have two NVIDIA TITAN RTX gpus for CUDA and an Intel gpu to run the displays.

Note:  Secure boot is not enabled and
commands shown below were run as `sudo -i`

**Install activity from the NVIDIA Linux [Install Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html):**

```
$ lspci | grep -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e92
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1e02 (rev a1)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1e02 (rev a1)

$ uname -m && cat /etc/*release
x86_64
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic

$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 8.4.0

$ apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
linux-headers-5.4.0-48-generic is already the newest version (5.4.0-48.52~18.04.1).

$ apt-get install nvidia-driver-455
nvidia-driver-455 is already the newest version (455.23.05-0ubuntu1).
nvidia-driver-455 set to manually installed.
```

**With the prerequisites met, install CUDA**

```
$ apt-get install cuda
cuda is already the newest version (11.1.0-1).

$ apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
nvidia-cuda-toolkit is already the newest version (9.1.85-3ubuntu1).
```

**Perform post-installation actions:**

`/usr/local/cuda-11.1/bin` was added to `PATH` via `.bashrc`

`/usr/local/cuda-11.1/lib64` was added to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` via `.bashrc`

**Recommended Action - install `nvidia-persistenced`**

```
$ /usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced --verbose
nvidia=persistenced failed to start.
```

**Syslog reports:**

```
Failed to query NVIDIA devices. Please ensure that the NVIDIA device files (/dev/nvidia*) exist
```

**Other tests:**

```
$ ls /dev/nvidia*
ls: cannot access '/dev/nvidia*': No such file or directory

$ cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
cat: /proc/driver/nvidia/version: No such file or directory

$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

$ prime-select query
intel

$ lshw -c video
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:df000000-df07ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:dc000000-dcffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:dd000000-dd07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:167 memory:db000000-dbffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

****It seems to me that the fact that `/dev/nvidia*` and `/proc/driver/nvidia*` are missing is the root cause of my issue, but I don't see what I did wrong, nor how to resolve it.**

All suggestions/advice is appreciated!